# Firebase Firestore and Functions 404 ERR_ABORTED

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

whenever I run a local server of my HTML page I get this error in the console (cloud functions are NOT being hosted locally):

```
GET https://www.gstatic.com/firebase/9.16.0/firebase-firestore.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://www.gstatic.com/firebase/9.16.0/firebase-functions.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I am aware that this is a topic that has been asked about before, but none of the solutions others came to has helped me in any way. The other modules load fine. Here is my reference to all the modules in my HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebase/9.16.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebase/9.16.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

Here is my firebase config at the beggining of my JS:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyB_gTZfsFfyrn_xsnNmtWuUMQkoyuHztts",
authDomain: "form-ce7e9.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "form-ce7e9",
storageBucket: "form-ce7e9.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "479728355456",
appId: "1:479728355456:web:e7ce8a6a21e33cd176fe65",
measurementId: "G-GHTPHK5QXS"
```

Here is my index.js which I have deployed successfully:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

// add trigger (new user signup)
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // for background triggers you must return a value/promise
  return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.id).set({
    email: user.email,
    cybos: [],
  });
});
```

And finally here is my firebase.JSON:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help we be greatly appreciated, I'm about to be tearing my hair out

UPDATE:

This message appeared another time I ran the HTML on a local server:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

It appears twice, once for firestore and once for functions

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is running into this issue it was actually a really simple solution, so I feel pretty dumb. I had the incorrect url's for the script reference, check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries) for all of the appropriate links. My version number was incorrect is what it boiled down to.